# How to update from python 2 to python 3 in terminal on Mac

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I've downloaded python 3 from their website. When I do 'python --version' in terminal it says I'm on Python 2.7.10.  How do I update it to what I just installed?

Comment: locate the installation and change PATH in .profile.

Comment: on Linux python automatically creates `python3`, `python3.6`, `python3.7` and also `python2`, `python2.7` so I can easily use selected version.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using 'python3 --version'? To use python 3 you have to be explicit and type python3 in the command line.

Comment: Aight, done that. Do I have to reinstall all the libraries? I just got this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests, time, smtplib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Comment: @MarcoWyatt every version has own folder for modules and you have to install for every version again - they may not works if you only copy them. Even 3.6 and 3.7 use own versions. But it is good time to clean up and skip not used modules